# Angular 2 CLI - Deployment to github user page shows readme page

Tags: angular, github-pages, angular-cli

I have deployed my angular 2 project to my github user page via angular CLI. I tried out the steps from [official angular 2 cli page](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli).  However when I try to access the github url it shows the contents of readme file.  Both the user page and user-page/baseUrl does the same.

I have used routing which works in the local environment. I’m not sure if I should modify the production environment variables or baseUrl.

Link to the repository: https://github.com/nirmalks/nirmalks.github.io

Comment: Are you trying to host your site in github, or use it as a git repository?

Comment: Host it as a static site in github for my github user page.

Comment: what is the host you make your http get request for angular website ?

Comment: It's a static SPA in angular 2 . There is no backend.

Comment: client side and server side both hosted on servers that listen to HTTP requests.. where is your client code hosted ?

Comment: Can I not host the content via the master branch in github for user pages?

Comment: Github is a git repository. In order to run and view the content of your website via browser, rendered and presented, you need to host it on web server. Maybe you can try to host it at https://pages.github.com/

Comment: I'm sorry if I couldn't make it clear.  I have tried using github pages. That's what I refered to as gtihub user page. https://nirmalks.github.io/ links to the readme page of the repo.

Comment: What is the response when you run the ng github-pages:deploy command? I thought this created a new branch called gh-pages and deployed from there.

Comment: It shows successfully deployed at nirmalks.github.io . Yes the new branch has been created.

Answer (score 3):

You should commit dist/ folder generated by `ng build` in master branch of your repo. As I can see you have your angular source code commited there. Unfortunatey you cannot keep your source code in your master branch.

the complete commit command with ngh will be 
`ng build --prod --base-href="YOUR_GITHUB_USER_NAME.github.io"` 
 and then 
  `ngh --message="MESSAGE" --branch="master"`

I have published the same in my repo you can check [my website](https://shivamsngh.github.io)

Also, the source code repo is [this](https://github.com/shivamsngh/shivamsngh.github.io)

Answer (score 1):

Step 1:

First install the angular-cli-ghpages globally:

$ npm install -g angular-cli-ghpages

build your project and set the correct base href location:

```
ng build --prod --base-href="https://user-name.github.io/repo/"
```

Then:

$ ngh

Step 2: In github.com --> Go to your repp --> Setting --> Choose publish with gh-pages branch ==> Save

Step 3: You need to run **ng server** in terminal to start your local project.

Step 4: And then come back to https://username.github.io/project/"

Answer (score 0):

Because you're using a **user/organisation repository** of the form **username.github.io** github automatically publish your **master** branch, it is also using the **readme** file as an index.

If you want to publish your **gh-pages** branch, you need to go in your repository **settings** and change **source branch** in the github pages tab to **gh-pages**

Answer (score 0):

Deploy Angular with GitHub pages

## First install angular-cli-ghpages globally

```
npm install -g angular-cli-ghpages
```

## Angular CLI with the --base-href

```
ng build --prod --base-href="https://<user-name>.github.io/<repo>/"
```

## To publish the app

```
ngh
```

just try on git 
you will be satisfied

Answer (score 0):

when you install the `npm install -g angular-cli-ghpages` that time github created a gh-pages branch in your repository, you need to only select that gh-pages branch option

Go to your repp → Setting → GitHub Pages &rarrl select gh-pages branch

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**1. Create Github repo**

If you had not created a Github repository prior to this, go ahead and create a repo in your Github account. After creating the repo, commit all your changes and push them to the repository you have created.

If you had created your repo prior to this, also commit and push all your changes to your Github repository.

**2. Install angular-cli-ghpages**

Run:

```
$ npm i angular-cli-ghpages --save-dev
```

if you hadn't installed angular-cli-ghpages.

**3. Run build**

Run:

```
$ ng build --prod --base-href "https://GithubUserName.github.io/GithubRepoName/"
```

**4. Deploy to gh-pages**

Run:

```
$ npx angular-cli-ghpages --dir=dist/Project-name
```

Make sure you put the name of the project in the place of Project-name.You can find this in the *angular.json* file under *defaultProject* which is at the bottom of the file.

Now if you visit *https://GithubUserName.github.io/GithubRepoName/* you should see your application running remotely,which means it has successfully been published on gh-pages.

Answer (score 0):

After 4 years i am using angular 11 now but i came across same problem.
To fix it:

1. Run `ng build --prod --output-path docs --base-href /<project_name>/`
   After this code was executed, "docs" folder should be exist.
2. You should commit and push this folder to your github repo.
3. On github repo page, go to settings and scroll down to Github pages and select branch which you pushed /docs folder and select folder /docs and click to save button.
4. To check, click the URL that given Github Pages section.

I did same things but in a kind of funny way when i click URL i saw blank page and i opened developer tools and i noticed request address of css and js was wrong.

It was like https://.github.io/[project-name]/scripts.7d5...00b7.js
It was wrong because of project name in URL. It should be repo name not a project name(My repo and project name isn't same)

So, i changed build code like that `ng build --prod --output-path docs --base-href /<repo_name>/`and did above steps again.

And finally **It works**.